# Null value in spark streaming from Kafka

Tags: java, apache-spark, apache-kafka, spark-streaming

I have a simple program because I'm trying to receive data using `kafka`. When I start a kafka producer and I send data, for example: "Hello", I get this when I print the message: `(null, Hello)`. And I don't know why this null appears. Is there any way to avoid this null? I think it's due to `Tuple2<String, String>`, the first parameter, but I only want to print the second parameter. And another thing, when I print that using `System.out.println("inside map "+ message);` it does not appear any message, does someone know why? Thanks.

```
public static void main(String[] args){

    SparkConf sparkConf = new SparkConf().setAppName("org.kakfa.spark.ConsumerData").setMaster("local[4]");
    // Substitute 127.0.0.1 with the actual address of your Spark Master (or use "local" to run in local mode
    sparkConf.set("spark.cassandra.connection.host", "127.0.0.1");
    // Create the context with 2 seconds batch size
    JavaStreamingContext jssc = new JavaStreamingContext(sparkConf, new Duration(2000));

    Map<String, Integer> topicMap = new HashMap<>();
    String[] topics = KafkaProperties.TOPIC.split(",");
    for (String topic: topics) {
        topicMap.put(topic, KafkaProperties.NUM_THREADS);
    }
    /* connection to cassandra */
    CassandraConnector connector = CassandraConnector.apply(sparkConf);
    System.out.println("+++++++++++ cassandra connector created ++++++++++++++++++++++++++++");

    /* Receive kafka inputs */
    JavaPairReceiverInputDStream<String, String> messages =
            KafkaUtils.createStream(jssc, KafkaProperties.ZOOKEEPER, KafkaProperties.GROUP_CONSUMER, topicMap);
    System.out.println("+++++++++++++ streaming-kafka connection done +++++++++++++++++++++++++++");

    JavaDStream<String> lines = messages.map(
            new Function<Tuple2<String, String>, String>() {
                public String call(Tuple2<String, String> message) {
                    System.out.println("inside map "+ message);
                    return message._2();
                }
            }
    );

    messages.print();
    jssc.start();
    jssc.awaitTermination();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Q1) Null values: 
Messages in Kafka are Keyed, that means they all have a (Key, Value) structure.
When you see `(null, Hello)` is because the producer published a `(null,"Hello")` value in a topic.
If you want to omit the key in your process, map the original `Dtream` to remove the key: `kafkaDStream.map( new Function<String,String>() {...})`

Q2) `System.out.println("inside map "+ message);` does not print. A couple of classical reasons:

1. Transformations are applied in the executors, so when running in a cluster, that output will appear in the executors and not on the master.
2. Operations are lazy and DStreams need to be materialized for operations to be applied.

In this specific case, the `JavaDStream<String> lines` is never materialized  i.e. not used for an output operation. Therefore the `map` is never executed.

Comment: Okay thanks. For Q1, how can i omit the key in Java (I'm not familiar with scala). And for Q2, what can I do for print the message? Thanks again

Comment: Q1-> use a map function. There're plenty of examples around. Q2 -> Do the same as you did for the `messages` DStream.

Comment: Okay I'm looking for the map function of Q1, I hope find something. For Q2, I do not understand you, what I have to do exactly?

Comment: @MohamedSaidBenmousa `lines.print()` ?

Comment: ah okay, Now i understood you! I will try it.

Comment: Now worked as I wanted, thank you, now I understand how it works!