# Spark Context on Bluemix adds null to json payload

Tags: apache-spark, ibm-cloud, message-hub

I am streaming messages from Message Hub to Spark instance in Bluemix. I am putting a simple json message to Message Hub using java client.

JSON Message -

```
{"country":"Netherlands","dma_code":"0","timezone":"Europe\/Amsterdam","area_code":"0","ip":"46.19.37.108","asn":"AS196752","continent_code":"EU","isp":"Tilaa V.O.F.","longitude":5.75,"latitude":52.5,"country_code":"NL","country_code3":"NLD"}
```

When I start streaming in Spark, the message I receive has an extra null at the beginning.

```
(null,{"country":"Netherlands","dma_code":"0","timezone":"Europe\/Amsterdam","area_code":"0","ip":"46.19.37.108","asn":"AS196752","continent_code":"EU","isp":"Tilaa V.O.F.","longitude":5.75,"latitude":52.5,"country_code":"NL","country_code3":"NLD"})
```

Please let me know why the Spark context puts this null in front. How can I remove it?

KafkaSender Code -

```
  KafkaProducer<String, String> kafkaProducer;
  kafkaProducer = new KafkaProducer<String, String>(props);
  ProducerRecord<String, String> producerRecord = new ProducerRecord<String, String>(topic,message);

  RecordMetadata recordMetadata = kafkaProducer.send(producerRecord).get();
  //getting RecordMetadata is possible to validate topic, partition and offset
  System.out.println("topic where message is published : " + recordMetadata.topic());
  System.out.println("partition where message is published : " + recordMetadata.partition());
  System.out.println("message offset # : " + recordMetadata.offset());
  kafkaProducer.close();
```

Thanks
Raj

Comment: Your problem seems similar to this one
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36888224/null-value-in-spark-streaming-from-kafka
your key is missing so message hub(kafka) added null for you, i doubt spark context adds that.

Answer (score 0):

Your key is null - the first value is your key, the second is your value of course.

I would recommend you post the code that posts messages to Kafka/MessageHub for a better answer.

To solve your problem - if your goal is just to print it out you can do something like this instead, which will print the data to stdout and ignore the null key.

```
stream.foreachRDD(recordRDD => {
  recordRDD.foreach(record => print(record._2))
})
```

Comment: Again, the producer code in question is not sending the key. I'm not sure what the issue is for you? You get a tuple of String, String back.. just use _2 of the tuple to get your value.